# Subsurf doesn't use creases outside of edit mode

Tags: subdivision-surface

I couldn't find anything on google, but as soon as I tab out of edit mode, subsurf ignores the creases I set. I just use the standard settings, and I never had problems like that before. Is there maybe a project setting or something that controls how creases are used which I accidentially changed?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Alright, found the problem. A boolean before the subsurf messed up the creases.